# A commutative variant of the exterior algebra

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, exterior-algebra

Consider $A = \mathbb{R}[t_1,\ldots,t_{k}]$, the ring of real $k$-variate polynomials in the indeterminates $t_1,\ldots,t_k$. For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, define the element $p(y) \in A$ through
$$
p(y) = t_1 y + t_2 y^2 + \cdots + t_k y^k \in A\,.
$$

Let $I$ be the ideal in $A$ generated by $\{p(y)^2 \mid y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and let $S = A/I$ be the quotient algebra of $A$ by $I$.

Has $S$ been studied? Does it have a name?

Comment: Your ring $S$ is a fairly simple ring (your description makes it look harder than it is). Is there something specific that you want to know about this ring? I do not know whether this particular ring has been studied exclusively in literature.

Comment: @Mohan If you see a much simpler description of the ring, please feel free to add it to the question. The description I gave is the one that popped up in my application. I am interested in performing fast arithmetic in the ring, where "fast" means roughly in time $O(d\log^c d)$ for some $c$, where $d$ is the dimension of $S$ (which is easily determined).

Comment: Let $u_m=\sum_{i+j=m} t_it_j$ for $2\leq m\leq 2k$. Then $I$ is generated by the $u_m$s.

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of this (you get the dimension from that very quickly), but wasn't not sure if this was overall a more useful way to look at it. Is there any striking property of ideals of this form, or any well-known special class of rings that this falls into that comes to your mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=\infty$, this algebra appears when studying integrable representations of level 1 of the Lie algebra $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_2$, see, for example, discussion in Section 2 of

[A. V. Stoyanovsky, B. L. Feigin. Functional models for representations of current algebras and semi-infinite Schubert cells. Functional analysis and its applications, 28 (1994), 55–72.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01079010)

The case of finite $k$ is used when applying when applying this sort of representation theoretic construction to obtain new combinatorial identities. In particular, in the notation of the paper

[B. L. Feigin, S. A. Loktev. On the finitization of the Gordon identities. Functional analysis and its applications, 35 (2001), 44–51](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1004172516908)

your algebra has the name $D_2(1,1,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry Vladimir, I hadn't seen your answer until now. I'll have a look. Thank you.